# How to fix this issues: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.text.Editable android.widget.EditText.getText()' on a null object reference

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I have read the other post that are already on here but can't seem to figure out why I am getting this error. The error is in the title and it is also here: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.text.Editable android.widget.EditText.getText()' on a null object reference

I tried to add msg = (EditText)v.findViewById(R.id.msgTxt); but that still didn't fix anything.

```
public class HelpFragment extends Fragment {
Button sendEmail;
EditText msg;


@Nullable

protected void process(View view) {

    }

public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_help, null);
     sendEmail = (Button)v.findViewById(R.id.SendBtn);
      sendEmail.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v){
          msg = (EditText)v.findViewById(R.id.msgTxt);
           String message = msg.getText().toString();
            sendEmail(message);
        }

    });
        return v;
}
    protected void sendEmail(String message){
    String to= new String("em@sd.xo");
    String subject=("a message from app");
    Intent emailIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, to);
    emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, subject);
    emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, message);
    emailIntent.setType("message/rfc822");
    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent, "Email"));
}

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You reference `onClick`'s `View`. You should implement `msg = (EditText)v.findViewById(R.id.msgTxt);` before `onClick()` method

You should use `editText.getText().toString()`, because `editText.getText()` returns `Editable`

---

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_help, null);
     sendEmail = (Button)v.findViewById(R.id.SendBtn);
     msg = (EditText)v.findViewById(R.id.msgTxt);

      sendEmail.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v){
           String message = msg.getText().toString();
            sendEmail(message);
        }

    });
        return v;
}
```

Comment: where should I add that>

Comment: @Beyazid thank you. I didn't even realize that and I'm also new to coding so thanks for the quick response and explanation that you gave me.